# Use of checkbox in linked button with that checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, button, checkbox

The button is linked to the value check box. When I press the button, the value of the check box changes, but when I select the check box, it is automatically undone because it is in the same button. How can I solve this easy

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName("AUTO_SHUTDOWN_TOGGLE")[$(this).val() - 1].checked == false) {
  document.getElementsByClassName("AUTO_SHUTDOWN_TOGGLE")[$(this).val() - 1].checked = true;
} else {
  document.getElementsByClassName("AUTO_SHUTDOWN_TOGGLE")[$(this).val() - 1].checked = false;
}

<button class="AUTO_SHUTDOWN_BUTTON" value="5"><span>Auto Shutdown</span>
<input type="checkbox" class="AUTO_SHUTDOWN_TOGGLE"></button>
```

Comment: The code you've provided doesn't reproduce the issue. Can you please reproduce a valid example?

Comment: can you explain more please? as i could understand you want to make checkbox button unclickable, and the only way to change its value is by clicking on the button right?